# Django app on Windows Server 2012 - HTTP Error 500.0 - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: django, iis, fastcgi

I setup a django "hello world" app IIS (Windows Server 2012). The application is run successfully using the Django web server. However, when I tried to install in on IIS (following the instructions provided [here](https://medium.com/@ayushi21095/steps-to-deploy-python-django-web-application-on-windows-iis-server-379b2b87fcf9)) I get an HTTP 500 error with the message "python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly".

I have seen numerous related posts on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work for me. Based on the guidance

- I have checked file permissions on both the app and virtual environment folder but they in my opinion this should not be the issue as the users IUSR and IIS_IUSRS can Read & execute, Read and List folder contents.
- I have tried also to run `wfastcgi-enable` based on the instructions provided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043072/python-exe-the-fastcgi-process-exited-unexpectedly) but I get the error "ensure your user has sufficient privileges and try again". Please note that I tried running it both from an "elevated" command line and also power shell with no results.
- I have reinstalled python to make sure it is installed for "all users" (as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709620/django-on-iis-process-exited-unexpectedly)) but I get an error "0x80070659 - This installation is forbidden by system policy".
- I looked in the Event viewer but I could not find something useful.

My questions:

- Is there a specific log that I should check? How could I find it?
- My django app does not have a web.config file. Should I create one?

My setup: Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5, Python 3.9.1

Comment: Have you tried checking the Application and System logs under EventViewer?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes I did. However, nothing suspicious came up. Should I look for something specific? Obviously I miss something here...

Comment: There are many reasons for this error. first of all, the php version may cause this error, you can try to install Python 3.6.8 or other version. If you still can't solve the problem, please post more detailed information about the error page.

Comment: @samwu The python version is 3.9.1. I don't see how the php version might be relevant though... When you say "more detailed information" what do you mean? Is there a specific log file that I could share?

Comment: "Detailed information" means the information of your error page, you can post a screenshot of it.